# Представить или предоставить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, паронимы

В связи с этим просим до 30 марта **предоставить (представить)** информацию согласно таблице, а также предложения о принятии мер...

Answer (score 3):

Если это требование к *форме представления* информации, то "**представить** информацию в виде таблицы"; если же в таблице размещены элементы *запрашиваемой* информации, то "**предоставить** информацию" (согласно требованиям, приведённым в данной таблице).

Comment: Если бы это **было** требование к форме... Но на деле это требование о предоставлении информации и предложений.

Comment: Я тоже склоняюсь к тому, что имелось в виду второе, но не на 100% уверен.

Answer (score 0):

Корректно: *В связи с этим просим до 30 марта **предоставить** информацию согласно таблице, а также предложения о принятии мер...*

> Паронимы: предоставить — представить
>   предоста́вить — предста́вить
>   Слова составляют паронимическую пару. Часть речи слов: глаголы.
>   Составляют гнездо пар с паронимами: предоставивший — представивший, предоставленный — представленный, предоставив — представив, предоставление — представление.
>
> **предоставить**
>   1. Отдать кого-что-либо в распоряжение, пользование кому-чему-либо.
>   2. Дать возможность кому-либо сказать, сделать что-либо, чем-либо распорядиться.
>   Примеры:
>   1) предоставить кредит, заём, концессию, помощь, место, участок, помещение, удобства, должность;
>   предоставить себя воле волн, течению;
>   2) предоставить возможность, выбор, права, независимость, слово.
>
> **представить**
>   1. Предъявить, сообщить что-либо кому-либо.
>   2. Познакомить с кем-либо, дать возможность ознакомиться с чем-либо.
>   3. Признав достойным чего-либо, ходатайствовать о чём-либо (о награде, повышении по службе и т. п.).
>   4. Воспроизвести в мыслях, вообразить кого-что-либо (обычно со словом «себе»).
>   5. Изобразить, показать кого-что-либо.
>   Примеры:
>   1) представить документы, отчёт, заключение, факты, доказательства, список, справку, рукопись;
>   2) представить гостя, нового сотрудника, дебютанта, научный труд, характеристику;
>   3) представить к награде, к званию, на соискание премии;
>   4) представить мысленно;
>   представить интересную картину; 
>   представить пейзаж; 
>   представить сложность задачи;
>   5) представить сцену из спектакля;

(http://paronymonline.ru/%D0%9F/270)